# How to configure indent tabs on prettier git action?

Tags: github, github-actions, prettier

I've added a git action to prettify my code.
The problem is that when it prettify, it makes 2 tabs indenation and I cant find where to config it to be 4 tabs (or any other prettier configuration).
How do I set a custom configuration to prettier git action?

Here is the yml:

```
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - validation

jobs:
  prettier:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # Make sure the actual branch is checked out when running on pull requests
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}

      - name: Prettify code
        uses: creyD/prettier_action@v4.3
        with:
          # This part is also where you can pass other options, for example:
          prettier_options: --write **/*.{js,md}
```

Comment: Use `--tab-width` with `prettier_options`. See https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width. You can test it with [prettier's online playground](https://prettier.io/playground/) too.

Comment: Thanks! it should be something like prettier_options: --tab-width 4?

Comment: Yes, that should do it i.e. `prettier_options: --write **/*.{js,md} --tab-width 4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`--tab-width` *prettier* CLI option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width) .

```
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - validation

jobs:
  prettier:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # Make sure the actual branch is checked out when running on pull requests
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}

      - name: Prettify code
        uses: creyD/prettier_action@v4.3
        with:
          # This part is also where you can pass other options, for example:
          prettier_options: --write **/*.{js,md} --tab-width 4
```

Please note that `prettier_action@v4.3` is [just executing `prettier <prettier_options>` command on the runner](https://github.com/creyD/prettier_action/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L74). So if you have more options to add you can specify it in the `prettier_options`(Should be separated by spaces)